Wordpress custom taxonomies URL with dash instead of slash
I am trying to get a custom URL structure for a custom taxonomy and it should be like this:
/football/team-xxx
where xxx wil be the term (name of the team).
If in the rewrite array of the register_taxonomy function I insert
'slug' => 'football/team-'
the result is an url like
football/team-/barcellona instead of football/team-barcellona
I would like to get an URL like
football/team-barcellona
